# codeigniter ajax request with session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

cant get session values through ajax request

this is my ajax req

```
$.post(url, payload, 
    function(returnedData){
        console.log(returnedData); //does not print session values it seems session has restarted
         var jsonData = JSON.parse(returnedData);

         $('#cart').empty().append(jsonData.data);
});
```

output in console.log

```
    Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1473660791
)
```

assigning session variable

```
public function test($id=null)
{
    $_SESSION['tot']=1;
}
```

testing not using ajax

```
public function addToCart($id=null) //note that this is also the control for my ajax req
{            
        print_r($_SESSION);
        die('0');
}
public function test1()
{
    print_r($_SESSION); // it prints fine
}
```

output

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1473660731 [tot] => 1 )
```

> I autoload my session library.
>   CI says it doesnt matter on how you access session variables either using session magic or the php as long as it exist.

Comment: if you use php session then you need to start implicitly session_start() before accessing $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Im using codeigniter session and I autoload it.

Comment: if you use code igniter session then access it as $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');

Comment: I believe that it is also the same as accessing it via $_SESSION['name']. And i already tried this one, it also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you use please default codeignitor session and please mention which url you make ajax request and php code of ajax request

like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('tot',1);
```

and then print the session array like this

```
echo "<pre">;print_r($this->session->userdata('tot'));
```

Comment: Ok ill try that one

Comment: still the same. it prints ok when im not accesing it through ajax req.

Comment: So only addToCart function it will not print and other functions it will print ok?

Comment: "addToCart" will also print ok if not through ajax request. Say if ill just access "addToCart" direct in my url bar, like typing the whole domain (ex. http://localhost/khloe/welcome/addtocart), it prints fine. But if i use ajax request like "$.post()", then its not working. I hope you get what im trying to say. Thanks for the quick reply by the way

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
 public function test($id=null)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('tot', 1);
        //instead $_SESSION['tot']=1;
    }
    public function addToCart($id=null) //note that this is also the control for my ajax req
    {            
            $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
echo $session_id;
    }
    public function test1()
    {
        //print_r($_SESSION); // it prints fine
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
echo $session_id;
    }
```

> and make sure session library loaded ($this->load->library('session');)